# finding the average of the inputs from a file

Tags: java

Hi guys I seem to have trouble with a program

A sample input can be as follows:

```
3 1 2 3 

0 1 12

-12

14 1 2 3 

5 1 2 3 4 5 6 

4 10 20 30 40
```

Sample output has to be :
The average of the values on line 1 is 2.0

> *** Error (line 2): Line is empty - average can't be taken
>
> *** Error (line 3): Header value of 0 - average can't be taken
>
> The average of the values on line 4 is 12.0
>
> *** Error (line 5): Corrupt line - negative header value
>
> *** Error (line 6): Corrupt line - fewer values than header
>
> *** Error (line 7): Corrupt line - extra values on line
>
> The average of the values on line 8 is 25.0
>
> There were 3 valid lines of data
> There were 5 corrupt lines of data

This is what I have so far :

```
public class DataChecker
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File myFile = new File("numbers.text");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(myFile); 
        int count=0,count2=0,sum=0;
        int[] val = new int[50];
        String line = null;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {              
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line); 
            count++;
            while(lineScanner.hasNextInt()){
                lineScanner.nextInt();          
                count2++;
                
            }
            
            if(lineScanner.hasNextInt())    
                val[count2] = lineScanner.nextInt();    
            
            for(int i =0;i<count2;i++) {
                sum += val[i];
                sum = (sum/count2);
                System.out.println(sum);
            }
            
            System.out.println("There are " + count2 + " numbers on line " + count);
            lineScanner.close();
            count2=0;
            
        }
        
        scanner.close();
    }
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

You are not taking a proper tally of the numbers on each line.  The algorithm should be to read in a line, tokenize it using a scanner, then consume integers until there are no more.  Keep track of both the total sum and the number of ints seen, then take the quotient of these two sums to get the average.

```
// your initialization code
int numLines = 0;

while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {              
    line = scanner.nextLine();
    Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line); 
    numLines++;
    int count = 0;
    int total = 0;

    while (lineScanner.hasNextInt()) {
        total += lineScanner.nextInt();
        ++count;
    }

    if (count == 0) {
        System.out.println("Line " + numLines + " has no numbers.");
        continue;
    }

    double avg = 1.0d * total / count;
    System.out.println("The average of the values on line " + numLines + " is " + avg);
    lineScanner.close();
}
```

Comment: thank you very much but for the empty lines its saying what the pervious line says

Comment: @AliAhmad I cannot reproduce this behavior ([demo](http://rextester.com/KUK27676)).